# Postgresql db From localhost to heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I already have a DB hosted in local. Now I would like to run my application in Heroku. All goes fine but I don't know how to create DB on Heroku and migrate all my models.

On localhost I have a config file:

```
{
  "development": {
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "admin",
  "database": "",
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "dialect": "postgres"
},
"test": {
"username": "postgres",
"password": null,
"database": "",
"host": "",
"dialect": ""
},
 "production": {
"username": "postgres",
"password": "admin",
"database": "",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"dialect": "postgres"
 }
}
```

My index in models:

```
'use strict';

 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
 const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
 const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
 const config = require(__dirname + '/../../config/config.json')[env];
 const db = {};


let sequelize;
  if (config.use_env_variable) {
   sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
 } else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  config
);
 }

fs
.readdirSync(__dirname)
 .filter(
 file =>
  file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === 
'.js'
)
 .forEach(file => {
  const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
  db[model.name] = model;
 });



db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

// FOREIGN KEY SETTING FOR USER


module.exports = db;
```

And i have scripts that i run like that:

```
"setupDev": "createdb -U postgres shc-dev; NODE_ENV=development sequelize -U postgres db:migrate",
"setupProd": "createdb -U postgres humansocialcomputation; NODE_ENV=production sequelize -U postgres db:migrate",
"resetDev": "dropdb -U postgres shc-dev",
"resetProd": "dropdb -U postgres humansocialcomputation",
"start": "node app.js",
```

My goal is to use this scripts on heroku too, how can i achive that's goal?
Also, i already have a database and db_url from Heroku but this DB is not empty. How can I also rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

See [the docs for pg:restore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

For example:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: I need a script to run on heroku console for db:migrate